# `web3-eth-contract` instance throws error on using `setProvider(RPC_URL)`

Tags: web3js, typescript

I created an instance of `web3-eth-contract` and then called the `setProvider(..)` function on it according to the official documentation of Web3.js, but I end up getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Contract.setProvider is not a function
    at getAccountRecoveryContract (smart-wallet.ts:16:14)
    at HTMLButtonElement.splitPrivateKeyIntoShards (smart-wallet.ts:32:37)
```

Here's my TS code:

```typescript
var Contract = require('web3-eth-contract');

const CONTRACT_ADDRESS: string = "0x2ACDe8bc8567D49CF2Fe54999d4d4A1cd1a9fFEA";
const RPC_URL: string = "http://localhost:8545";

function getContract(): any {
    Contract.setProvider(RPC_URL); // here
    var contract: any = new Contract(ContractABI, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
    return contract;
}
```

[Web3.js documentation link](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/web3-eth-contract.html#web3-eth-contract)

Point to note: I'm using `"web3": "^4.3.0"` but I don't seem to find the documentation on for v4+ in their documentation. I checked the comments in the source code of `web3-eth-contract` module and found the same mention of `setProvider(..)` function there as well.